# What is the bit depth of the alpha channel in CSS3 colors?

Tags: css, alpha, rgba

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503286/iterate-through-colors-in-javascript), I realized I haven't been able to find a clear answer to what the bit depth of the `a` part of `rgba` and `hsla` in CSS3 colors actually is. I've hunted through various W3C documentation, but aside from specifying that alpha is *represented* as a [`float range 0.0% - 100.0%`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-def), and [the definition for the bit depth of the alpha channel in PNGs](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-DataRep.html), I don't really have a clear picture (haha) of what the limits of the alpha channel in CSS3 actually are. Can someone find something more normative?

Comment: For a canvas, according to MDN, [_CanvasRenderingContext2D_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D), `.globalAlpha` is a _float_, as is the parameter for `.setAlpha`. A canvas can also CSS-notation colours, so I'd expect the same data type, though I fear unless someone wants to find the CSS's colour implementation in the source code..

Comment: @PaulS. that's what's so frustrating about the W3C's float representation: A float is a *terrible* way to represent a finite set of values. Now, maybe they wanted to leave room to expand the set beyond any specific number of bits, but a float just makes that ambiguous.

Comment: I thought a float would be a useful way, as many things can change alpha; opacity settings of the node, parent nodes, other alpha in things above and below, alpha in images, a float would reduce the error of adding and multiplying them all together to calculate how it should be rendered.

Comment: @PaulS. it doesn't reduce the error, it just obscures it. The error is still there, compounded by floating point errors.

Comment: True, but compared to working in int staight away, working in float (calculate) then converting to int as the last step (for render) has much reduced error; `int(0.4) + int(0.4) = 0` (0.8 error) vs `int(0.4 + 0.4) = 1` (0.2 error) -- assuming rounding rather than floor, but you get the idea. For floor consider `1.1` and `0.9`.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to Mozilla Developer Docs on opacity in rgba aka alpha aka "a" in rgba:

[alpha docs on mozilla developer org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)

opacity

The opacity CSS property sets the opacity of an element. Opacity is the degree to which content behind an element is hidden, and is the opposite of transparency.

Syntax

```
opacity: 0.9
opacity: 90%

/* Global values */
opacity: inherit;
opacity: initial;
opacity: revert;
opacity: revert-layer;
opacity: unset;
```

Values :

a (alpha - value in Number) in the range 0.0 to 1.0, inclusive, or

a (alpha - value in % ) in the range 0% to 100%, inclusive, representing the opacity of the channel (that is, the value of its alpha channel).

Any value outside the interval, though valid, is clamped to the nearest limit in the range.