# Why is the alpha value represented as a float?

Tags: css, rgba

Is there a particular reason for why RGBA colors are represented by three 8-bit color values and one [poorly defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503485/what-is-the-bit-depth-of-the-alpha-channel-in-css3-colors) floating point value?

I mean, in the end, the alpha value does translate into something binary. Right? So I don't get the point in having three well-defined values, and one which I can only guess how accurate it is.

For instance, if I use the value 0.1 - what will the end result *really* be?

Comment: You would be better off asking [www-style](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style).

Comment: Are you saying there is no proper place to ask this at Stack Exchange?

Comment: I'm getting the impression that you're looking for a history lesson on the HTML standard, specifically as it relates to colors.  You're also implying pretty heavily that how colors are defined in the HTML standard is in some fashion 'wrong'.

Comment: Part of what I wish for is some decent documentation, yes.

Comment: It's the percentage of the layer that will be shown. For example at 50% half the pixels will be the colour specified. The maths is quite complex. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing

It needn't be a float, it could be a byte with a value between 0 and 255. For example, the OpenGL documentation defines a colour in this fashion. (see glColor4b). Similarly the colours can be floating points too.

Comment: In terms of why it's a float in CSS. It looks like it's based on the SVG specification which describes a formula http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-SVG11-20030114/masking.html#SimpleAlphaBlending So my best guess is that it made the maths easy and obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Alpha is a percentage (0.1 alpha = 10% opacity) and it's common to specify percentage in floats since they are more precise.

If you used integer for percent representation you would probably specify it like `(int)10 = 10%`. This works fine for even numbers, but say for some reason you want to be very exact, like 10,3%. What would that be in integer? 103 could be confused with 103%.

The point is that floats can specify any percentage very precisely, while ints cant. Thus, percentage values are represented by floats. Ex:

> 0% = 0.0f
>
> 105% = 1.05f
>
> 74,31985% = 0.7431985f
>
> etc.

Even though some of this doesn't become a problem in the case of alpha color, it's just good practice to make percentage-representations floats.

Comment: But does the percentage really represent what happens in the end? I guess what I'm saying is this: Doesn't the alpha value translate into an integer value somewhere down the line? Or how does the browser render .1 of something? And IF that is the case, isn't the added precisioun spurious? Also, why is it so hard to find out how precise the floating point representation is?

Comment: I have no idea ^^ I just figured that the reason it is float is because that's just how people represent percentage :P

Answer (score -1):

the a in rgba is for opacity.

`color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);` will display a black colour that is 50% opaque.  the value goes from 0 to 1.  if you want a darker colour, try 0.7 or 1 for full solid black.

Comment: Well, yes. Obviously. But why is it not an integer value?