# Create darker shades of color in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

I am trying to write a piece of code that will take an original color, then insert x amount of div's into an html block. The problem is, I won't know what the original color will be and I need each block inserted to be a shade darker or lighter than the last. I figured using the HEX code would work but it wasn't very successful. What is the best way to do this?

Here is my code for reference:

```
var color = "db4848";
           for(var i = 0; i < coins.length; i ++){


                widget += "<div style=\"padding-top:6px;padding-left:50%;height:40px;background-color:" + color + ";color:white;border:1px solid #ffffff\">" + coins[i].coinType + "</div>";
                //color = color - 10; (How would I do this??)
           }
           document.getElementById("coinDisplay").innerHTML = widget;
```

Also, making the color var "0x------" formatting changed the color and did not work when I subtracted from it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503286/iterate-through-colors-in-javascript)

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/7p6xedL9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use RGB color coding instead of hex... you can also convert your incoming value to rgb.

the numbers go from 0 to 255. 0 is zero amount of that color. 255 is max amount of that color. so rgb(255, 100, 0) is max red, medium amount of green, and zero blue.

white is rgb(255,255,255). black is rgb(0,0,0)

suppose your incoming color was rgb(200,100,50).  then rgb(190, 90, 40) would darken it a bit. rgb(180,80,30) would darken it more.  if you want to preserve the color tone, decrease each value by percentages rather than by fixed values.  so if you decreased by 10%, then rgb(200, 100, 50) would become rgb(180, 90, 45).

an interesting thing happens if you go past zero.  you could then wrap around and start at the top.  so if you got to this: rgb(10, 5, 0) your next color could be rgb(0, 250, 245). but that would be a big color jump.